# define Vue directive styles

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-directives

I am looking for a solution how to define styles for a custom directive.

What I mean. I have created awesome directive which manipulates text content and implements clamping for it. This directive adds and removes classes depending on the toggle state.

And everything works perfect except that fact, that this code is not modular, so I cannot create simple npm package - because if someone wants to use it, he should add css classes to his styles.

So does someone knows how to create modular directive which contains styles?

P.S.: I know that I can directly assign styles to the element like `el.style.height`. But it is not a beautiful solution.

**UPDATE:** here is the directive https://jsfiddle.net/Todmy/vzqmc4mh/6/

Comment: Can you post code example or a small version of your directive.

Comment: @samayo yes, sure. Question is updated.

Comment: So the question was what exactly? When users download your app, you don't want them to apply the style? instead you want to somehow 'provide' it with your app without using `e.style...` is that it?

Comment: @samayo exactly

Comment: Then in that case, you should use [single file components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) you can see where the style is placed, you can put your style there and use the export default {} for your logic

Comment: A directive doesn't seem like the right fit here. You can do with a lot less work and hackery using a component.

Comment: @BillCriswell Is that for me? I think it makes sense

Comment: yes. I know about components :) I decided to use directive because this functionality should be additional to the component(like color change). Anyway, thank you for your answers.

Comment: No @samayo. I was agreeing with you.

Smytro: A component wouldn't limit you in any way. Going to make a quick POC.

Comment: @BillCriswell it is not necessary. I can do it myself :)

Comment: Okie dokie. I definitely think using a directive will be more trouble in the end though! Good luck!